# Can we do a scatter plot of 2 groups with only one trend line for both in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

So i want the scatter plot to have 2 different color dot groups belonging to 2 different groups but only one trend line the goes across all the dots despite the color. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that can be done.  Use a helper series that has duplicates of all the data points of the two groups. Then add that helper series to the chart. Create the trend line on the helper series. Then format the helper series to have no markers and no line, so it becomes invisible, and also remove it from the legend.

[image]